# Nested I18n locales in Middleman

Tags: middleman

I've setup locales in my Middleman installation, using the files `locales/en.yml` and `locales/ar.yml`.

The challenge is that I've got a lot of darn text to translate, and would like to have things nested like so:

```
---
en:
  main_page:
    hello_and_welcome: "Hello and Welcome to ..."
    bye_and_well_bye: "Bye now"
```

I could previously access the words as `I18n.t(:hello)` in my pages. How would it work when I'm using nested YAML?

Tried `I18n.t(:main_page, :hello_and_welcome)` but that returned:

> {:hello_and_welcome=>"Hello and Welcome to ..."}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the reference as a String:

```
<%= I18n.t('main_page.hello_and_welcome') %>
```

or with the short tag:

```
<%= t('main_page.hello_and_welcome') %>
```